# instantiate python object immediately after its class definition

Tags: python, odoo, instantiation, python-module

In a large python project (openerp) I encounter several times the following pattern:

In a module, a class with its methods is defined. Then, in the same module and immediately after the class definition, an instance of the class is instantiated, that is then called from other modules.

```
# in module_A.py:
class ClassA(object):

    def __init__(self, default="Hello world!"):
        self.default = default 

    def my_method(self, data):
        print self.default
        print data

object_a = ClassA()
```

To me it looks simpler to define the methods as module functions, without the class lookup overload:

```
# in module_B.py:

default = "Hello world!"

def my_method(data):
    print default
    print data
```

Seen from other modules, the usage is very similar:

```
from module_a import object_a as prefix
prefix.my_method("I'm so objective!")
```

versus:

```
import module_b as prefix
prefix.my_method("I'm so modular!")
```

Is there any rationale to prefer pattern A over pattern B? Or is pattern B more pythonic?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0&feature=youtube_gdata_player does not answer your question but this might interest you.

Comment: As you mentioned OpenERP, this is find for classes that are not OpenERP models but do not do this for OpenERP models.  In OpenERP < 7 you do need to instantiate each model yourself but then OpenERP manages a singleton instance that you should access using self.pool.get.  HTH, Adrian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, you want different clients to be able to use your module with different settings in such a way that they don't conflict with each other. For example, Python's [`random`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module provides a bunch of random number generation functions that are actually bound methods of a hidden `Random` instance. Most users don't care too much what algorithm generates their random numbers or whether other modules asking for random numbers will change the sequence. However, users who do care can get their own `Random` object and generate sequences of random numbers that won't be affected by other modules asking for random numbers.

Sometimes, something that's global now might not always be global. For example, if you're working on a planetary-scale RTS, you might have a `Planet` class with one instance, because the battle only happens on one planet. However, you don't want to rule out the possibility of building something like Planetary Annihilation, with battles stretching across entire solar systems and dropping extinction-event asteroids as superweapons. If you get rid of the `Planet` class and make its methods and attributes module-level, it'll be much harder to go back and add more planets later.

Sometimes, it's more readable to have objects doing things instead of modules. For example, suppose module `joebob` defines two objects `evil_overlord_bob` and `good_guy_joe`.

```
class Bob(object):
    def slaughter_everything(self):
        print "Muahahaha! Die for my amusement!"
class Joe(object):
    def stop_bob(self):
        print "I won't let you hurt those innocents!"
evil_overlord_bob = Bob()
good_guy_joe = Joe()
```

Suppose Bob and Joe are very unique people. It's unthinkable that you'd want to create another object anything like Bob or Joe. In that case, you could move `slaughter_everything` and `stop_bob` to module-level and get rid of the Bob and Joe classes and objects entirely. However, then you'd be writing

```
joebob.slaughter_everything()
joebob.stop_bob()
```

It's much clearer what's going on if you can say

```
evil_overlord_bob.slaughter_everything()
good_guy_joe.stop_bob()
```

even if you'll never need to instantiate Bob's equally-evil twin brother `greg_the_fleshripper`.

Comment: So your main argument would be that classes are more reusable than modules. On the other hand, the video linked by Josay (comment to the question) argues against this as a form of premature implementation.

Comment: The goodguy/badguy example could easily be written in pattern B style as two separate modules.

Comment: @QuantMetropolis: I don't know whether the classes are a good idea in your case. I don't know the code you're looking at or the design of the system. I'm just giving examples of cases where you might reasonably prefer a class with a single instance to module-level functions and state.

Comment: While you could implement Bob and Joe as two modules, they are logically grouped very tightly together. Putting them in separate modules would require two imports for what would make more sense as one dependency, and it would still be less understandable to have Bob represented by `<module 'bob' from '/path/to/bob'>` than by `<joebob.Bob object at 0xabcdefab>`. Also, you'd probably have a circular import in the `bob` and `joe` modules, and no one wants that.

Answer (score 0):

Among other benefits, using classes allows you to use the introspection on the instances, which is something you cannot do with functions.

In a more general way, both approaches are "pythonic". Use one of the other really depends on the type of project (small/big, with/without GUI, ...)

Comment: Well, you can do introspection on modules, which would be the equivalent in pattern B of object introspection.